# Is it possible to use a 32-bit ODBC driver with a 64-bit application on windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, odbc, windows-server-2008, 64-bit

I have a 64-bit application and an ODBC-driver which only comes in 32-bit-flavour. Is there any way to have the application connect to the datasource through the driver?

I realize the short answer is NO, related to 64-bit applications not being able to load a 32-bit dll, but I am looking for a slightly longer and more positive answer.

Re-writing the driver is not an option at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Host the ODBC-driver in a 32-bit process, and communicate between your now 64-bit application and the process.  Pick your [IPC of choice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574(VS.85).aspx) for doing so (I'd probably go with sockets, for no particular reason).

Here's an [article](http://www.dnjonline.com/article.aspx?ID=jun07_access3264) that discusses this approach, and some of the implications.